# Why was Boba Fett considered the greatest bounty-hunter in the galaxy?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, boba-fett, bounty-hunters

In the *Star Wars Holiday Special*, Darth Vader says this to Boba Fett:

> I see why they call you the best bounty hunter in the galaxy.

This seems to be the general attitude of most characters towards Fett. It's also common to hear fans describe him as the greatest bounty-hunter in the *Star Wars* galaxy.

However, in the actual films, he doesn't do all that much. He helps capture Luke and Han, which was impressive, but not really enough to justify being called the best bounty-hunter in the galaxy.

What exactly has he done in the expanded universes to deserve this title?

I'm not asking for arguments as to why he is or isn't deserving, what I want is a list of his greatest and most impressive canon bounty-hunting accomplishments.

I know he was a powerful fighter who did many impressive things. However, **if it isn't bounty-hunting related, it doesn't answer the question**.

Comment: Pretty early on in the Clone Wars he brought down an entire cruiser of clones (I'm not sure what class it was) while trying to kill Mace Windu for one thing.

Comment: @Hatandboots That's impressive, but not really bounty-hunting. Also, he ultimately failed to kill his prey.

Comment: I don't know if I agree with you. Consider how great he looked when he failed to hit anyone on Jabba's barge, had his gun chopped in half, then when he had a clean shot at luke he shot some kind of rope around him instead of using the gun on his wrist, which he later fires at luke as he flips to the other barge. Then to top that off, he accidentally gets slapped in the back with barely any force and the armor his vast experience has selected malfunctions and throws him into a wall, then into a pit to be digested over 1000 years. Sounds like a true champion to me... boba fett... pfft!

Comment: lol @KaiQing - although - the new canon book "Aftermath" dropped some clues that Fett's story may or may not be over.

Comment: Being renowned enough to appear before Vader count?

Comment: Well, his backpack's got jets.  He's Boba the Fett.  He bounty hunt for Jabba Hutt to finance his 'Vette.  He chill in deep space.  A mask is over his face.  And he deliver the prize, but he still narrow his eyes, cuz his time he don't like to waste.

Comment: “what I want is a list” — list question! Vote to close!

Comment: He's got a cool suit? Honestly he dies such a pathetic death in rotj, of course he gets ressed by fans and an entire couture is invented for him.

Comment: @KaiQing You bring up these points about how Boba Fett isn't such a great bounty hunter given his actions on the sail barge.  But, in the Star Wars universe, _he still might be the best_.

Comment: I was wondering where you were getting this from; I quit reading after *"Holiday Special"*....

Answer (score 12):

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boba_Fett/Legends#Legendary_exploits has a pretty good compilation. Some that I liked:

- Destroyed entire Bounty Hunter guild (ultimately, on behalf of the Emperor)
- Survived Sarlacc
- Destroyed entire Imperial garrison on Vryssa
- Killed  Jhordvar (who happened to be a *Noghri* assassin - who elsewhere in EU gave trouble to Luke Skywalker).

Also, in Fett's own words,

> "The Hutts and all my other clients-they pay me the kind of bounties they do because of one thing. I deliver. Once I've caught my prey, nothing stops me from bringing it in. Nothing. If I take on a job, I complete it. And everyone in the galaxy knows that." (src: *The Mandalorian Armor*).

Ironically, EU coverage of Fett totally belies that assessment, for **storytelling reasons**: Fett routinely comes up against Star Wars protagonists, who of course must ultimately win. So, he frequently (relatively) loses his bounties to Lando Clarissian, Han Solo etc...

Yet, he even manages to lose in style (e.g., after [fighting Darth Vader to near standstill](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boba_Fett/Legends#Duel_on_Maryx_Minor)).

Comment: _EU coverage of Fett totally belies that assessment, for storytelling reasons_. Always the way :)

Comment: Is surviving the Sarlacc canon? I hope not :(

Comment: At least two of those examples don't really count as "bounty-hunting achievements."

Comment: If you edit the list to include more examples of actual bounty-hunting, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @AndresF. Thus far, there is nothing in Disney Canon to suggest that Boba Fett survived the sarlaac pit. But given that he's an inexplicably popular character, I'm guessing that this is something that will eventually migrate over from Legends, especially if they start telling more stories set between Episodes VI and VII.

Comment: er....maybe not @Thunderforge - there is an interstitial in the new canon book "Aftermath" that seems to be the initial seeds of planting doubt as to his desime

Comment: @AndresF. it is now.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica yes, sad. Much like Maul not dying in Phantom Menace. It's the nature of both fandom and studio execs to keep milking the proverbial cash cow beyond all sense and reason :(

Comment: @Thunderforge your guess proved correct, sadly. After all these years, it's indeed canon that Fett survived the Sarlacc pit. Another nail in the coffin of Star Wars, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a super long list but as far as I know he is the only person who ever survived being eaten by the Sarlacc.

He was also named  Mandalore (or the leader of the ancient warrior race of Mandalorians widely regarded as the most deadly race in the galaxy) which means he is the best warrior among them .
As for in the films at the time what would have been considered impressive in the 70's is much different then today and they didn't have any EU to establish his character with and there was no real standard of what a Mandalorian should be, at that time he just looked impressive but to us now we have the EU and Jango Fett to compare him to that is why he seems lackluster

Comment: Again, while impressive, neither of these are really "bounty-hunting achievements."